# After parsing Json acquired with API, it can not be assigned to a variable in Swift

Tags: ios, json, iphone, swift4

I create an iOS App use swift4

I get one problem.
After parsing Json acquired with API, it can not be assigned to a `var stores : [categories.stores]?`. print value is **nil**

but print`let json = try decoder.decode(categories.self, from: data)`, I can get Json data.

And there is no error. so I don't know why I can not substitute

please help me.

**StoreListViewController**

```
class StoreListViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var TableView: UITableView!


var category_id = ""
let cellReuseIdentifier = "cell"
// use json 
var stores : [categories.stores]?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    TableView.delegate = self
    TableView.dataSource = self

    let url = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/api/category?category_id=" + category_id)
    let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    let session = URLSession.shared

    let encoder: JSONEncoder = JSONEncoder()
    encoder.dateEncodingStrategy = .iso8601
    encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted

    session.dataTask(with: request){(data, response, error)in if error == nil,
        let data = data,
        let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse{

        let decoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
        do {

            let json = try decoder.decode(categories.self, from: data)

            // in to stores variable
            self.stores = json.stores

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.TableView.reloadData()
            }
        } catch {
            print("error:", error.localizedDescription)

        }

        }

        }.resume()

    print(stores as Any)
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return stores?.count ?? 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? TableViewCell
        else {
            fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of TableViewCell.")
    }

    cell.storeName.text! = stores![indexPath.row].name
    cell.storeLocation.text! = stores![indexPath.row].location


return cell
}

}
```

**DataModel**

```
struct categories : Codable {
let id : Int
let name : String
let stores : [stores]

struct stores : Codable {
    let id : Int
    let name : String
    let location : String
    let price : String
    let open_time : String
    let closed_day : String
    let photos : [photos]
    let tags : [tags]

    struct photos:Codable {
        let id : Int
        let path : String
    }

    struct tags:Codable {
        let id : Int
        let name : String
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It prints `nil` because the `print` line is outside the closure and will be executed before returning the data. Put the line inside the closure. If no data is displayed the error must be somewhere else. And please name your structs with a starting capital letter and in singular form (`struct Photo : Codable`). One instance of the struct is one `Photo` not one `Photos`.

Comment: I see. I bchanged. thank you so much

Comment: PS: And declare the data source array `stores` as non-optional `var stores = [Category.Store]()` to get rid of the bunch of ugly question and exclamation marks and weird syntax like `stores?.count ?? 0`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was working in before the closure.